# the limit of floor function

Tags: calculus

the limit of this function when x approach to zero from the right:

$f(x) = \frac{1}{\lfloor x \rfloor}$
is **not** defined am I right?

Comment: **Mathematica** gives: `ComplexInfinity` -represents a quantity with infinite magnitude, but undetermined complex phase. **Maple** gives: `undefined`-

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk what is the final answer ?

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk